# Docker order of parameters results in exited container

Tags: docker

The following command *works* and results in the container continuing to run

```
$ docker run --name mysql -d -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=P@ssword1 mysql:5.7.31
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS                               NAMES
fd096c5aa2f6        mysql:5.7.31                                           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 seconds ago       **Up 3 seconds**               0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   mysql
```

If I change the placement of the port definition (put it at the end) the container exits immediately

```
$ docker run --name mysql -d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=P@ssword1 mysql:5.7.31 -p 3306:3306
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS                    NAMES
c723a5e63da0        mysql:5.7.31                                           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 seconds ago       **Exited (1) 2 seconds ago**                            mysql
```

Can someone explain why this is? It seems at odd with just about every other application where the order of the command line *options* arguments is largely irrelevant. It is also very difficult for a new user to work out what is wrong and a poor experience.

Oddly too, if the `-p 3306:3306` is omitted the container works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of options is completely irrelevant. That said, the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) clearly states that for `docker run` command options be must be specified before the name of the image, like in your first and third example.

In your second example `-p 3306:3306` is after the image name and is therefore considered to be a command to be run inside the container. Since it's not a valid command, the container exits immediately.

Finally, you last example works, because exposing ports is not mandatory.